# CGContextSetAlpha is acting like multiply

Tags: ios, draw, paint, alpha

I have a painting app, and if i paint a red dot, then try to paint over it with a yellow dot but at a low alpha value it acts like a multiply blend mode, even if i keep going over the red dot with the yellow. Shouldnt it start to cover up the red dot, even if the yellow alpha is 0.5 or another lower value? How can I make a low alpha value continue to build up when applied and cover a color with a higher alpha? I'm I making sense?

Im calling these methods below in this order with red, then changing the color to yellow and drawing over the red, the result is in the attached image.

```
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor();
    CGContextSetAlpha();
    CGContextMoveToPoint();
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect();
    CGContextFillPath();
```

thanks

[image: Yellow never covers the red dot at low alpha even if i keep painting over it]

Comment: You'll need to show us the code that does the blending. It depends entirely on how you've implemented it.

Comment: The thing is that i have done no blending, nor do I want it to blend. This is a result of simply drawing on an opaque circle with a more transparent one. Ill add the codes now.

Comment: @TheWay He/she means that you'll need to show enough of the code to use that we can run it, not just a set of functions you're using.  The args, returns values, and other computations you're doing are important for understanding the issue you're facing and providing a solution.